# I've tried everything and still getting Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Rectangle {
Scanner scanner;
int tlx;
int tly;
int brx;
int bry;
int px;
int py;
void doRectangle () {
    scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    tlx = scanner.nextInt ();
    tly = scanner.nextInt ();
    brx = scanner.nextInt ();
    bry = scanner.nextInt ();
    px = scanner.nextInt ();
    py = scanner.nextInt ();
if (tlx>brx || tly>bry){
  System.out.println("error");
  return;
}
if (tlx <= px && px <= brx && tly <= py && py <= bry) {
  System.out.println("inside");
} else {
  System.out.println("outside");
}
}
}
```

Please help me I compiled a million of times then run and always the same thing Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]. PLease help me I really want to know where is my mistake or what I am missing

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Read the error message: "does not have a static void **main** method accepting String[]".

Answer (score 9):

The error message is telling you what's wrong. You need a main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // program starts here
}
```

From here, you can run the code you have:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.doRectangle();
```